# Calculus Limits in Higher Dimensions

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x,y) = y/x,$ does lim$(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ $f(x,y)$ exist?

My take take is $y = r\sin(\theta)$ ; $x = r\cos(\theta)$.

$y/x = r\sin(\theta)/r\cos(\theta) = \tan(\theta)$. Then

lim$(r,r)\rightarrow(0,0)$ $\tan(\theta)$ defined at $(0,0)$, thus limit exists.

However, the textbook says the limit does not exist. How so$?$

Comment: How do you conclude that $\theta$ tends to $0$ ?.  That is your mistake. Think about it

Answer (score 0):

Take $x = t, y =2t \Rightarrow  \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{y}{x} = 2$, and let $x = y = t \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{y}{x} = 1$.

Comment: how would you go about graphing this function? The textbook also says the domain of f does not include the y-axis. Why is this?

Comment: The domain does not include the $y$-axis because the expression $y/x$ is meaningless for $x=0$.